# Source of Subtotal for Credit Memos

Tags: creditmemo

Our Magento database was wiped a few weeks back (long story!) and I used the MySql logs to restore it. That worked for the most part but there was one order I had to restore manually. I thought I had done that successfully but we don't seem to be able to create a Credit Memo for the Order. Specifically, the subtotal column is not being populated correctly - it's showing zero for both item rows. These totals are populate correctly on the order and invoice.

My question is what database table is the subtotal sourced from?[image: Credit Memo Product rows showing zero subtotal]

Answer (score 1):

Each order item will be stored in the table `sales_flat_order_item` this will contain the row total and tax information shown in your screenshot.

For the creditmemo items these are stored in the table `sales_flat_creditmemo_item`